# Batch subscribe users with Mailchimp API

Tags: curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

As per the API documentation here https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#create-post_lists_list_id, the API makes it possible to batch subscribe several users, by sending a JSON object containing a members field. That members field is an array of status, email_address and merge_fields.

When sending the following cURL query, I get a response saying the email_address field could not be found.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/123456789/members \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic SSSSHWONTTELL=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{"members": [{"email_address": "myuser@yahoo.fr", "status": "subscribed", "merge_fields": {"LNAME": "ANQUE", "FNAME": "PATRICIA"}}]}'
```

And the response :

```
{
    "type": "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title": "Invalid Resource",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.",
    "instance": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "email_address",
            "message": "This value should not be blank."
        }
    ]
}
```

The query looks good to me, in respect with the API documentation. I'm probably missing something. Any idea ?

Please note that the query works properly for individual members sent as {email_address:XXX, status:XXX, merge_fields:XXX}, but I wish I could send an array of those.

Comment: remove /members from the url

Comment: every other thing looks good

Comment: @Jalasem Would you mind suggesting this as an answer please, since it works properly ? Thank you !

Comment: post it as a proper answer. I will approve it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jalasem, removing /members fixed this issue.